# centering div within div with uneven padding

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the problem. I'm given a div with uneven top and bottom padding. There is a text box centered in the div. Like so:
[image]

as the user adds more text, the text box will expand both up and down, until it hits the top padding (since the top is padded more).
[image]

if the user adds more text, the text box will only expand downwards, until it hits the bottom padding.
[image]

if the user continues adding text, the outer div will expand to accomodate.
I have tried messing with padding in the outer div, but the text box will then center slightly lower in the div (to account for the extra padding on top). Any ideas on how to circumvent this? here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zfoenx3/43/)`with some starter code`.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: working on an example in jsfiddle right now @CornelRaiu

Comment: What do you want it to do when the there's a lot of text? Should the apparent bottom padding match the top one? Should the apparent top padding get smaller?

Comment: @Brother58697 the padding should always be the same, and the text should never enter the padding. Once the text expands down to the bottom padding, the whole div should start expanding.

Comment: That's how it's acting in your code. What's going wrong in the example you made? Unless by the padding being the same you mean top and bottom should eventually be equal.

Comment: I understand the scenario, but I don’t really understand what you want to happen, or what problem you’re having. I can’t tell from the summary given when what you are describing is what you want, and when what you are describing is something you want to stop from happening.

Comment: what I am describing is what I want @SamSabin. Currently, the text-box is centered in between the margins, rather than the top and bottom border of the outer div. This gives the text box an off center look (bad). It needs to be perfectly center in the div. As the user types, it expands outwards, first hitting the top padding, and then only down to the bottom padding. Then the whole div should start expanding.

Comment: @NikhilMishra Ohhh gotcha. That makes sense now 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do this way let me know if this will work. I flex the text then wrap it. let me know.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  width:500px;
  display: table;
  padding: 20px 10px 40px 10px
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.inner-wrapper span {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
   padding: 40px 10px 20px 10px
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
<div class="inner-wrapper"><span>THIS IS A SAMPLE TEXT THAT NEEDS TO BE CENTER PLEASE CENTER ME</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not quite. The text is centered between the top and bottom margin here, not between the top and bottom border of the outer wrapper.

Comment: I added your padding and let me know if this is what you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `borders` for the `inner wrapper`, then you can add the missing padding to it whether top or bottom.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-height: 200px;
    width:500px;
    display: table;
    padding: 40px 10px 20px 10px;
  }
  
  .inner-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* border: 1px dotted black; */
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper"><span>
      hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there 
      hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there 
      hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there 
      hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there 
      hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there 
      hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there hello there 
    </span></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is close, but, while the padding at the bottom of the inner wrapper centers the wrapper properly, I don't want that padding to be creating extra space at the bottom when the text box is full.